# reading input from text file java

Tags: java

This is my input file:

```
4 4 3 2   //edges//vertex//must visit node//case
1 2 4// this are the graph node and its a directed weighted grap//
1 3 20
2 3 4 
3 4 4
1 4// source 1 to 4//
2 4 // source  2 to 4//
```

how to read the input file ?
1.for the first line user give the vertices,edges,a must visit node,case
2.
3.those line are representing  graph vertices ,edges and weight between them
4.
5.
using dijkstra algo from source 1 and destination 4
for last two line
6.

7.
i upload the new edited code also facing problem can you please go through it

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Adjacency_matrix {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    static int a[][];
    private static boolean[] checks;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try {
            FileReader f = new FileReader("E:\\dijkstra.txt");
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
            //    int[]v=new int[4];
            String[] v = b.readLine().split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
                int ver = Integer.parseInt(v[0]);
                int edg = Integer.parseInt(v[1]);
                int x = Integer.parseInt(v[2]);
                int test = Integer.parseInt(v[3]);
                a = new int[ver][ver];
            }
            String[] v1 = b.readLine().split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                int ver1 = Integer.parseInt(v1[0]);
                int edg1 = Integer.parseInt(v1[1]);
                int w = Integer.parseInt(v1[2]);
                a[ver1][edg1] = w;
            }
            String s;
            while ((s = b.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, " ");
                int src = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                int d = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            }
            System.out.println("Adjacency Matrix");
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    System.out.print(a[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

1. You're parsing 4 elements on the first line when there are only 3 (try changing the `catch` block to `e.printStackTrace()` to see where the program crashes).
2. You're not using `e` (the one you define, not the exception) or `c` in this code. That may be because you haven't provided the entire thing.
3. Commenting out the assignment to `c`, your array assignment fails because you are assigning indices based on `token1` and `token2` assuming a 1-based array instead of a 0-based array, thus it will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for the input line `3 4 4`
4. It then fails on the next line because there is no cost associated with `1 4`, yet your `while` condition will continue to add graph elements until there is no more input.

Comment: can you help me to read the input file and make a graph

Comment: You're on the right track, just match up your input to what you are doing with it. If you want to try for a bit and then come back (now that you should be able to see exactly what's failing and where), first search for any issues you run up against, then only post if those don't help.

Comment: i tried in a alternate way but also facing some problem can you help me to fix those problem.I updated the code can you go thorough it?

Comment: ask a new question if you have a new problem. The new code you have runs, but has quite a few unused variables.

Comment: facing arrayoutofbound exception,can you please show me how to run the code for that input file

Comment: When I run it with the code (and input file) you provided, it prints `Adjacency Matrix
0000
0040
0000
0000`